# Issue with calling publicly exposed method from event handler in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I keep getting an error `Cannot call method 'changeBackgroundColor'` of undefined. I have a click event set up to call a public method within my plugin. When that method is called programmatically it works, but if I click the element I get the error.

My plugin html structure is like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

Snipped from the plugin:

```
this.changeBackgroundColor = function() {
  $('#square').css('background','red'); 
};

//Note "this" is the .container so I bind click event to child square
    $('#square', this).bind('click', function () {
        //Error
       changeBackgroundColor(); 
    });
```

If I call `$('.container').myPlugin().changeBackgroundColor();` it works. But if I call `changeBackgroundColor` from the click event function it can't find the `changeBackground` function.

**Link to jsFiddle** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NVJDF/2/)

Note: I'm using jQuery 1.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "this" is no longer the same when you're inside that function. Mind you, your jquery object is not persistent, they're just reflections on collections of HTMLElements. Consider storing your event inside of .data or the like.

If I was to call $(".foo") twice in a row, I have 2 different objects, even though they reference the same HTMLElements.

But to fix your error do this:

```
this.changeBackgroundColor = function() {
    $('#square').css('background','red'); 
};

var _this = this;
$('#square', this).bind('click', function () {
    _this.changeBackgroundColor(); 
});
```

but the issue is the pattern :)

You may want to consider doing something like this:

```
var events = {
    changeBackgroundColor: function() {
        square.css('background','red'); 
    },
    changeItMore: function() {
        square.css('background','purple'); 
    }
};

var square = $('#square', this).bind('click', function () {
    events.changeBackgroundColor(); 
});

square.data("myEvents", events);
```

Now from other code, you can do:

```
var theObject = $(".foo", container).yourPlugin();
var yourEvents = theObject.data("myEvents");
yourEvents.changeBackgroundColor();
```

Another common pattern is custom events, like:

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
    square.css('background','red'); 
}

var square = $('#square', this).bind('click', function () {
    changeBackgroundColor(); 
}).bind("changeBackgroundColor", function() {
    changeBackgroundColor(); 
});
```

Now you can trigger that with:

```
$(".foo", container).yourPlugin().trigger("changeBackgroundColor");
```

Another common pattern that I accept, but everyone else maynot, is to have your plugin return an object that's not a jQuery object, and keep a reference to that around. I'm A'OK with that :)

Comment: Thank you, that solved the initial problem. Can you provide a link to a tutorial that shows the correct pattern?

Comment: Updated it for ya with a few common patterns.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: remove `this` from the function and it will work.

The one before:

```
changeBackgroundColor = function() {
      $('#square').css('background','red'); 
};
```

UPDATE 2:

If you want it public, do  `window.changeBackgroundColor()`

Comment: This seems to be a comment

Comment: I do not want to do that because in the real world the elements within `container` won't be id's and if I click the square I don't want all of the other widgets to change their squares background color. Please see my fiddle in question.

Comment: Updated answer please see post.

Comment: Doing that makes it a private method. I can use the click event, but if I try to use `$('.container').myPlugin().changeBackgroundColor();` it won't work.